# undefined method `each` for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following code and getting error of `"undefined method each&#39; for nil:NilClass"`

```
@loan_ids = params[:moredata].split(",").map { |s| s.to_i }
@loans_ids.each do |number|
  puts number
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Its `@loan_ids.each` not `@loans_ids.each`

Answer (score 1):

```
@loan_ids=params[:moredata].split(",").map{|s| s.to_i }
@loan_ids.each do |number|
   puts number
end
```

You have misspelled it

Answer (score 0):

It's `@loan_ids.each` not `@loans_ids.each`. You have a plural "loans" when it's not defined that way.